# PHP transform string to date period

Tags: php, regex, date, transform

I wonder how to do it!?
I have:

```
$datePeriod = '2010-09-13 - 2010-09-19'
```

I need output:

```
09/13/10 - 09/19/10
```

I thinking do it with strtotime() and date() native functions

```
date('m/d/Y \- \ m/d/Y', strtotime($datePeriod));
```

but strtotime() not accept this string straightly '2010-09-13 - 2010-09-19' i need to slice ,trim before i give it to strtotime() or date()? It this right approach or is more simple method than doing it with transform operations?

Comment: You're going to need to split that string into two separate dates, convert each format individually and then rebuild the string

Comment: Now i reading manual http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php but there not showed period example. How i cant do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` here with `strtotime` and `date`:

```
$datePeriod = '2010-09-13 - 2010-09-19';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b/', function($m) { 
               return date('m/d/y', strtotime($m[1])); }, $datePeriod);
//=> 09/13/10 - 09/19/10
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Your implementation are short and simple.

Answer (score 1):

php date formatting requires a single date as input and thus, you need to split and trim the dates.
easiest in this case will be to use the preg_split

```
$dates = preg_split("/ \- /",$string);
```

Now you have 2 dates in the $dates variable, which you can convert separately using strtotime as suggested in the question and later on concatenate them as per need